# Different results between headless mode and no headless mode python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping the follow web page using chromedriver, selenium and BeatifulSoup:

https://www.rappi.com.co/tiendas/exito-express/s?store_type=express_exito&query=man%C3%AD&search_type=TYPED&origin=general

I interact with the web page using selenium, after I asure I have the entire web page displayed I use BeatifulSoup to locate and extract information

I look for this element using BeatifulSoup

```
img = n.find("img", {"class":"ng-lazyloading"})["src"]
```

when I run the script in headed (no headless) mode, i got all src attributes, but when I run the script using headeless mode I just got the last ones src.

how can I get the entire src attribute using headless mode.

this is the set parameters:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--incognito")
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('window-size=1051x806')
#options.add_argument("start-maximized")
# options.use_chromium = True
prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)


look at the output
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try with selenium driver itself to get src links,

```
enter code here
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

img=[]

l=WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//img[@class='  ng-lazyloaded']")))

for i in l:
    img.append(i.get_attribute('src'))
```

Comment: Not working, adittionally it should be a beautifulsoup solution because I'm getting many elements through this way